# Prevent output of MongoDB BSON BinData in terminal

Tags: mongodb

I'm storing files within a regular MongoDB document without using GridFS (the files are all smaller then the limit of 16MB).

When taking this approach, I'm running into the problem that when I do for example a `db.collection.find` operation in the terminal it will output the entire binary data. For tiny files this is not a problem, however when the file is 8MB it takes around 20 seconds to output this binary file in the terminal.

Is there any way of preventing the outputting of the entire binary data to the terminal?

The document roughly has the following structure:

```
{
  _id: ObjectId
  field1: string
  field2: string
  field3: string
  attachment: {
                 filename: string
                 data: BinData
              }
}
```

If there is not `attachment` it will be left out of the document.

Comment: Do you want to not have it at all? What do you want instead of the entire binary data?

Comment: I would like to know that the document has an attachment, but not outputting everything to the console since it takes 20 seconds just to output it. I was think a possible solution was to store the binary data in a different collection and just store a reference to it in the actual document...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about you make sure that the query finds the documents that the field attachment [$exists](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/exists/) in them but exclude that field using [projection](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.find/#find-projection) from your results?

```
db.bindata.find({attachment:{$exists:true}}, {attachment:false})
```

You can extend your query of course. Just make sure you keep the additional condition.